# Posso chamar um metodo especifico no spring security sem está logado?

Tags: jsf, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Tenho uma aplicação feita em Spring Boot 2.7, estou usando spring security, gostaria de chamar um método no Back-end sem precisar estar autenticado, no entanto, ao clicar no botão "Chamar" ele me redireciona para a pagina de LOGIN sem chegar no método chamado:

Front:

```
<h:form autocomplete="off">
       <p:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" actionListener="#{chamadaController.teste()}" value="Teste" ajax="false" id="chamar" icon="pi pi-phone">
        </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Back:

```
public void teste() 
{
    System.out.println("Back-end"); 
}
```

Gostaria de chamar o método "teste()" sem precisar logar no spring security

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para permitir que um método seja acessado sem autenticação no Spring Security, você pode configurar o acesso não autenticado para esse caminho específico na sua classe de configuração de segurança.

Por exemplo, se você tiver uma classe de configuração de segurança, como a seguinte:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Aqui, o método **configure(HttpSecurity http)** configura as regras de autorização. A regra **antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()** permite acesso não autenticado a qualquer caminho que comece com "/public/".

Para permitir que o método **teste()** seja acessado sem autenticação, você pode adicioná-lo a um novo caminho em sua classe de configuração de segurança:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/teste").permitAll() // Novo caminho para o método teste()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Agora, o método **teste()** pode ser acessado sem autenticação no caminho "/teste". Então, em seu código Front-end, você pode atualizar o **actionListener** do botão para chamar o caminho "/teste":

```
<h:form autocomplete="off">
       <p:commandButton class="btn btn-primary" action="#{chamadaController.teste()}" value="Teste" ajax="false" id="chamar" icon="pi pi-phone">
        </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Note que também atualizei o atributo **actionListener** para **action** para indicar que estamos chamando um endpoint em vez de ouvir um evento.